# google maps polygon on click , show summary of markers within the polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

Need some help with google maps polygon areas. I have a many markers plotted across the google map. Have some polygon areas plotted on map too. I want to find the total of marker points covered by a polygon, whenever the polygon area is clicked. Kindly guide or provide some good links in this direction
Thanks.

Comment: The [geometry library poly namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) has a `containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)` method (Return Value:  boolean, Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [ray casting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). The implementation would be something like this:

```
var markers = []; // list of your markers
var polygonPath = polygon.getPath();
var location;

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    location = markers[i].getPosition();

    console.log(isPositionInside(location.lat, location.lng, polygonPath));
}

function isPositionInside(mLat, mLng, polygonPoints) {
    var isInside = false;

    for (var a = 0, b = polygonPoints.length - 1; a < polygonPoints.length; b = a++) {
        var aLng = polygonPoints[a].lng,
            aLat = polygonPoints[a].lat,
            bLng = polygonPoints[b].lng,
            bLat = polygonPoints[b].lat;

        if ((aLng > mLng) != (bLng > mLng) && (mLat < (bLat - aLat) * (mLng - aLng) / (bLng - aLng) + aLat)) {
            isInside = !isInside;
        }
    }

    return isInside;
};
```

This isn't the most optimal solution, as you can read in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon), but in most cases it will get the job done.